# Javascript if statement and && operator difference

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operator-keyword

what's the difference between this 2 code?

ONE: if xmlhttp.readystate==4, then if xmlHttp.status==200, then execute code

```
function handleServerResponse(){
   if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            if(xmlHttp.status==200){
               xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
               xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
               message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
               document.getElementById('underInput').innerHTML = message;
               setTimeout('process()', 1000);
         }else{
            alert('Something went wrong!');
            }
      }
}
```

TWO: if xmlHttp.readtState==4 and xmlHttp.Status==200 then execute code

```
function handleSxerverResponse(){
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
    xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
    xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documnetElement;
    message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
    document.getElementById('underInput').innerHTML = message;
    setTimeout('process()', 1000);
}else{
    alert('Something went wrong!');
}
```

}

They both look same to me, but only the first one did what I want, instead the second one keep showing the alert message.

Comment: The only difference is that in the first one, if readyState is not 4, you wont see the alert.

Comment: @thelmaeckman they both look the same to you? check that logic carefully ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the ready state is 4, it is 3. And then

- in the first case the outside test prevents the `alert`
- in the second case, the `else` clause applies so the `alert` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the first part is false.

In the case of `then if` you will never enter the block, so you will never see the alert in the second if statement. If you use `&&` you will enter the `else` block if either is false.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that in the first one, if `readyState` is not 4, you wont see the alert.

If you converted the first one to this:

```
function handleServerResponse() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById('underInput').innerHTML = message;
            setTimeout('process()', 1000);
        } else {
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Something went wrong!'); //added this
    }
}
```

They would functionally be the same thing. So with the first one you could easily customize the alert based on what 'went wrong' if you wanted.